# Can I include multiple variables in an if statement operator comparison?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to implement an `if` condition where I ensure two variables are within a certain range.

But, I want to somehow do it so I don't cause duplication (Example 1 <= x,y <= 100). Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
if (1 <= int(pizzeria_location_x) <= int(dimensions)) and (1 <= int(pizzeria_location_y) <= int(dimensions))
```

Comment: cleaner way to do it would be to make the check a function for either variable is within that range

Comment: If you have just 2 variables to check, your current code if probably the most efficient and explicit. Maybe just format it on 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could put `pizzeria_location_x` and `pizzeria_location_y` in a tuple and evaluate the condition with [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```py
if all(1 <= int(l) <= int(dimensions) for l in (pizzeria_location_x, pizzeria_location_y)):
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `all`:

```
if all(1 <= int(n) <= int(dimensions) for n in (pizzeria_location_x, pizzeria_location_y)):
    ...
```

If `pizzeria_location` is a tuple instead of two variables this becomes easier (and other operations may as well):

```
pizzeria_location = pizzeria_location_x, pizzeria_location_y
if all(1 <= int(n) <= int(dimensions) for n in pizzeria_location):
    ...
```